# Android Edit Text with inside buttons

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-image

In my application EditText need with following features:

1) Rounded corner.

2) both left and right side image button inside the edittext with click able.

[image]

How to design like above image.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xml tag,

```
  android:drawableRight="@drawable/close"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
```

Comment: I know it but image clicking is not possible.